# Importing mongoDB dump to arangoDB

Tags: mongodb, arangodb

I need to import everything that exists in a particular database in mongoDB to arangoDB. I can dump the mongoDB data as:

```
mongodump -d "database_name" -u "user_name" -p "password"
```

Which will then dump the database to a dump folder.

Now I need to import this dump to my arangoDB database. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

A method you can try is to first export your Mongo database into a JSON file as:

```
mongoexport --db databaseName --collection collectionName --out dump.json
```

Once you've obtained the JSON file you can try to import it into Arango using `arangoimp`

```
arangoimp --file dump.json --collection collectionName --create-collection true
```

**References:**

- [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)
- [arangoimp](https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/Administration/ImportingData.html)

Let me know if you encounter problems.

Comment: That would only import a single collection. I want the whole db

Comment: You would need some kind of script that iterates through every collection and dumps and imps for you. If mongodb has any list collection feature, this should be very simple.

Comment: This method works only in rare cases where the collections have no relations and there are no foreign keys, as the ids/keys won't be correctly vinculated.